# no module named simple_facerec

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, cmake, face-recognition

MacOS Catalina python version 3.8.2

Using opencv for real time face detection I tried.

```
'from simple_facerec import SimpleFacerec'
```

returns : `no module named 'simple_facerec'`

I tried `pip3 install cmake` --> `pip3 install dlib` --> `pip3 install face_recognition` to no avail.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: python -m pip install face_recognition

Comment: Import using: `from face_recognition.simple_facerec import SimpleFacerec`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this part `pip3 install cmake --> pip3 install dlib` doesn't seem to be correct.

You need to follow the documentation:

First, make sure you have [dlib](https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/629d75c1baac34dfa5ca2a1928a7aeaf) already installed with Python bindings.

And then:

```
pip3 install face_recognition
```

Check out the [source](https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/) for installation.

Comment: I've successfully installed dlib. pip3 install face_recognition still returns 'no module named simple_facerec'

Comment: I've already successfully downloaded and updated dlib :(

Comment: The documentation says installation with `brew`. You did it with `pip`. Maybe, you might wanna try with `brew`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to show what results you got from using the command in question, whether the installation was successful, and what the error message is.

You can try to install the `face_recognition` package using the `python3 -m pip install face-recognition` command.

If the package is already installed in one of your environments, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python:Select Interpreter` to switch the **correct** interpreter.